# Как сделать многостраничный тест с выбором правильных ответов, с аудиоматериалами и картинками в них?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Как можно реализовать многостраничность у теста, допустим так, чтобы можно было разбить, грубо говоря, по структуре:
1блок - 3 страницы вопрос с выпадающим списком + с выбором из ответов,
2блок - 3 страницы с аудио и картинкой и вопросами с выбором из ответов,
3 блок - 1 страница с вопросами с выбором из ответов
, но с возможностью перехода между разделенными страницами(с третьей страницы сверху нажав на кнопку 1 вернуться к первым вопросам, но чтобы на других страницах(как и на первой) ответы сохранились).
После теста посчитать кол-во правильных ответов и вывести уровень отвечающего(5 правильных - плохо, 10-хорошо условно.)

В голове много кусков, которые приложу, помогите собрать все воедино) буду крайне благодарен.
С аудио и картинкой - не умею делать(

Вопрос с ответом внутри предложения.`1. Вопрос?

How old

```
    <select name="street" id="select">
        <option>Выбрать</option>
        <option value="0">is</option>
        <option value="0">there</option>
        <option value="1">are</option>
        <option value="0">than</option>
    </select>
    
    you?
    </p>`
```

Вопрос с выбором одного из 4

```
<div class="quizsection">

<h2>2. Вопрос ?</h2>
 
<div class="answer">
    <input name="q1" value="true" id="value1" type="radio" checked="checked" /> Ответ 1
</div>

<div class="answer">
    <input name="q1" value="false" id="value2" type="radio" /> Ответ 2
</div>

<div class="answer">
    <input name="q1" value="false" id="value3" type="radio" /> Ответ 3
</div>

<div class="answer">
    <input name="q1" value="false" id="value4" type="radio" /> Ответ 4
</div>
```

Подсчет ответов

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

var result;

function check()

{

```
  var question;
  var true;
  var false;
   
   
  question = 1;
  true = 0;
  false = 0;
   
   
  result = "";

  var choice;
   
  for (question = 1; question <= 3; question++) {
   
     var q = document.forms['quiz'].elements['q'+question];

        for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
           if (q[i].checked) {
              choice = q[i].value;
           }
        }

        if (choice == "false") {
           value1++;
        }

        if (choice == "true") {
           value2++;
        }


     }

  if (true == 0) {
     // Нет правильных ответов
     result = "ocenka2";
  }

  else if (true == 1) {

     // Один правильный ответ
     result = "плохо";
  }

  else if (true == 2) {
     // Два правильных ответа
     result = "хорошо";
  }

  else if (true == 3) {
     // Три правильных ответа
     result = "отлично";
  }


  else {
     result = "404";
  }
```

}